# UITableView pagination, willDisplay loading infinitely

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination

I'm trying to implement a chat feature in my app which will mimic iMessages' pull to load more messages. My API sends 20 messages in each call along with pageIndex and other values to keep track of pages and messages.

I'm implementing pagination using TableView willDisplay and pull to refresh features.

I'm not able to add correct logic to load more messages in willDisplay and it's going into infinite loop. Can anyone point me to right direction by looking at below code?

```
import UIKit

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var messagesTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var messages: Messages!
var messageArray = [Message]()

// Pagination
var isLoading = false
var pageSize = 10
var totalPages: Int!
var currentPage: Int!

// Pull To Refresh
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    fetchMessages(page: 1, completed: {

        self.totalPages = self.messages.pageCount
        self.currentPage = self.messages.currentPage

        // Sort message by ID so that latest message appear at the bottom.
        self.messageArray = self.messages.messages!.sorted(by: {$0.id! < $1.id!})

        self.messagesTable.reloadData()

        // Scroll to the bottom of table
        self.messagesTable.scrollToBottom(animated: false)

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    })

}

// MARK: - Table view data source
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messageArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if !self.isLoading && indexPath.row == 0 {

        self.isLoading = true

        fetchMessages(page: self.currentPage, completed: {

            if self.currentPage == 0 {
                self.messageArray.removeAll()
            }

            self.messageArray.append(contentsOf: self.messages!.messages!)
            self.messageArray = self.messageArray.sorted(by: {$0.id! < $1.id!})

            self.messagesTable.reloadData()

            // Scroll to the top
            self.messagesTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)

            self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
        })

        self.isLoading = false
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as? MessageCell else {
        fatalError("Can't find cell")
    }

    return cell
}


private func fetchMessages(page: Int, completed: @escaping () -> ()){

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/....") else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error in fetching data..........")
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print(str) }

        do {
            let resultData = try JSONDecoder().decode(messagesStruct.self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("DispatchQueue.main.async")
                self.messages = resultData.data!

                completed()
            }

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }
    }.resume()
}

//Pull to refresh
@objc func refresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    fetchMessages(completed: {
        self.messagesTable.reloadData()
    })

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`willDisplayCell` is not the safe place to check if tableView is actually scrolled to bottom rather use `scrollViewDelegate`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if !self.isLoading && (messagesTable.contentOffset.y >= (messagesTable.contentSize.height - messagesTable.frame.size.height)) {
            self.isLoading = true

            fetchMessages(page: self.currentPage, completed: {[weak self]

                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                strongSelf.isLoading = false
                if strongSelf.currentPage == 0 {
                    strongSelf.messageArray.removeAll()
                }

                strongSelf.messageArray.append(contentsOf: strongSelf.messages!.messages!)
                strongSelf.messageArray = strongSelf.messageArray.sorted(by: {$0.id! < $1.id!})

                strongSelf.messagesTable.reloadData()

                strongSelf.currentPage = strongSelf.currentPage + 1
            })
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Tx, I've tried it. The first issue is that scrollViewDidScroll is called well before any viewXYZAppear methods are called and it goes onto fetch & reload table. Is this normal?

Comment: @davems : I personally prefer that rather than manually calling `fetchMessages(page: 1,` in viewWillAppear,  but Its little hard to believe that when there is no data in tableView condition `(messagesTable.contentOffset.y >= (messagesTable.contentSize.height - messagesTable.frame.size.height)` will ever pass

Comment: @davems : but if that happens for whatever strange reasons, it will relieve you from manually calling `fetchMessages(page: 1,` which is cleaner :) its kinda creating self starting loader mechanism :) but I hardly doubt if scrollViewDidScroll will ever be called if it has no content to begin with, even if it gets called am highly doubtful if it will pass through the condition. Please put a break point and check again

Comment: This is print for the very first time before any viewXXXApepar is called:
isLoading: false
messagesTable.contentOffset.y: 0.0
messagesTable.contentSize.height: 0.0
messagesTable.frame.size.height: 590.0

Condition becomes true.

Comment: @davems : hmmmm interesting gimme a second :) But believe me comment out your `viewWillAppear`s `fetchMessages(page: 1,` and you will see that you have nice pagination system that starts itself :P though starting itself wasn't the intention till then lemme check how I have solved it

Comment: @davems : Seriously that log is confusing me further, if contentSize.height is 0 why and how tableview will even scroll?? if it will not scroll scrollViewDidScroll can't be called. This does not make any sense, scrollView will scroll only if contentSize is greater than its frame, in your logs its very clear tableView frame is much higher than its contentSize so it can't scroll, can u please check if there is any other scrollView in frame? I can't get any other explanation. Anyway this should give you a stable reliable pagination system without getting into loop

Comment: TableView is inside another ScrollView. Remember I said Im implementing a chat feature, it has textView to type message which required that additional scrollView.

Comment: scrollViewDidScroll is triggered from UITextView hence this condition fails.